# How to dispatch redux actions using react-router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm trying to combine react-router v4, react, and redux.  Because react-router tracks the URL, I've opted to keep that piece of state out of the redux-model.

But i still need a way to to dispatch a redux action when a route change happens by react-router.  Where is the best place to do that?

My first attempt was to put it in the onClick attribute of react-router's Link:

```
render() {

  // link config
  const links = this.props.photo.album( album => {
    <Link key={album.name} 
             to=`/album/${album.name}`
             onClick={() => this.props.dispatchAction(album.name)} />
  })

  // route config
  return (
     <div>
         {links}
         <Route path={`/album/:albumName`} component={Album}/>
     </div>
  )
}
```

The idea is that, when a user clicks a link, the dispatchAction() will update the redux state and then the Album component gets loaded.

The problem is that if a user navigates to the URL directly (eg /album/a1), the action is never dispatched, since the link is technically never clicked.

Because of this I removed the onClick portion of the Link, and moved the dispatchAction to the lifecycle methods of the Album component:

```
class Album extends Component {
    // invoked when user navigates to /album/:albumName directly
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatchAction(this.props.match.params.albumName)
    }

    // invoked whenever the route changes after component mounted
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.match.params.albumName != nextProps.match.params.albumName) {
            this.props.dispatchAction(nextProps.match.params.albumName)
        }
    ....
}
```

Now whenever the Album component is mounted or its properties changed, it will dispatch the redux-action.  Is this the correct approach for combining these libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) does this for you by applying a middleware on your store that dispatches actions on route changes, also on the initial route change. It's definitely the cleanest approach.

The only downside is it's still alpha but we have been using it without any issues for a while. It is also part of the `react-router` additional packages repo for a while.

Comment: I see that react-router-redux will dispatch a LOCATION_CHANGE action containing the new url.  I can setup a reducer to listen for that action and update the store, but now I have to parse out the url. React-router already does this with it's match object.  Is there a clean way to parse the url in one place?

Comment: You can make your store the storage for the routing info that react-router keeps and read the required information from there inside your reducer.

Comment: I think this is probably the official way to combine the libraries, but I ended up switching away from react-router to redux-first-router.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `Route` component that dispatches your action in `componentDidMount`:

```
class ActionRoute extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { pathname } = new URL(window.location.href);
    const [albumName] = pathname.split('/').slice(-1);
    this.props.dispatchAction(albumName);
  }

  render() {
    return <Route {...this.props} />
  }
}
```

This will now dispatch your action whenever the route is loaded. Composability FTW!.

Side note: if you use `ActionRoute` for parameterized routes, (eg `/album/1` and `/album/2`), you'll need to also dispatch the action in `componentDidUpdate` as the component isn't unmounted / remounted if you navigate from `/album/1` to `/album/2`.

Comment: It looks like match.params isn't available from Route/ActiveRoute.  It's only after the routing has occurred that the match.params field gets filled out by react-router.

Comment: You're right, completely spaced on that. I've updated my answer to parse the album name out of the url manually.

Comment: If you feel very strongly about not doing this parsing yourself (which is valid), then your approach to putting the dispatch in the component rendered by the route is about as good as you can get imo.